# cmake failed to configure due to GL.h

Tags: cmake

I am trying to build `cmake 3.10.2` from source.
I already have cmake installed but an older version so I am running

```
cmake .
make
make install
```

but the machine I am on doesn't have gl and cmake fails on missing `gl/gl.h` is there a way to not require `gl.h`?

Comment: It depends on the project you are compilng. If it is a 3D game, then probably no.

Comment: Are you trying to build cmake itself or a project that uses it? If the former, maybe you could try [downloading](https://cmake.org/download/) the precompiled version. I can't see how cmake can have a OpenGL dependency.

Comment: I am building cmake itself and it's coming from some Qt5 user gui module but I am not sure how to turn it off

Comment: But it's not possible that you use already built cmake ?